# Tkinter Python: Bar Gauge?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to find an effective way to create a bar gauge in Tkinter. I've been using labels inside a frame and changing the background color to indicate the level, but this is extremely inefficient as it involves ten if statements, each with ten lines of code, for each gauge. Would anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction for how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking for but it sounds like a for loop and some functions would work better

Answer (score 1):

from the sounds of it you are simple after a progressbar, there are two such widgets in tkinter, one is part of ttk and the other is tix, they function much the same but the styling is different, and both of them can be linked to an `IntVar` and simply setting the value of the IntVar sets the progressbar.

1) ttk.Progressbar
see [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Progressbar.html)

2) tix.Meter
see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tix.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the Progressbar does not really have the functionality that I was look for. I actually went with @Joran Beasley's suggestion and used for loops to change the appropriate labels to the appropriate color. Thanks...